# The best singleton pattern since Java 5

Tags: java, enums, singleton, java-5

Since Java 5 it is said that the best way to create a singleton is by a single-element enum type.

Example:

```
public enum SuperSingleton implements Zooma{
    INSTANCE;

    /**
     */
    public void fightTheBattle(){
        System.out.println("I am fighting the battle!!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void runningWild() {
        //This is method implemented from the Zooma interface.      
    }
}
```

According to Joshua Bloch, the single-element enum type singleton is;

- more concise
- provides the serialization machinery for free
- and provides an ironclad against multiple instantiation.

I can see how it is more concise and how it provides an ironclad against multiple instantiation, 
**but how does it provide the serialization machinery for free?**

Is it something the singleton gets by being an enum?

Comment: +1 although I think singletons were created by, and I quote Mr Bush, "the enemy".

Comment: The answer is right in the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java

Comment: ok, that was pretty obvious. Thanks guys.

Comment: I love enums - but your Singleton won't be able to inherit anymore. @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822827/the-better-java-singleton-pattern-nowadays/5843931#5843931

Comment: I have to disagree with JB here, because it is *he himself* who disagrees with himself. E.g. he says *"don't use interface to declare constants"*, and gives the reason that *"constant use is not an interface, it produces semantic mismatch and noise, and the syntactic sugar gained (no need to use `static final` etc.) is not worth it"*. He uses a similar argument couple of times in EJ2... By analogy, one would say *"don't use enum to declare singleton class; singleton is not an `enum` - it produces semantic mismatch and noise, and the syntactic sugar gained is not worth it"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Enums are all extended off of the [`Enum` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), which implements `Serializable`.

Comment: Wow, that sounds risky, meaning, if the singleton has some kind of state and it's persisted twice in moments, the de-serialization of those objects might be unpredictable, and the Singleton might behave in unexpected ways.

Comment: @Augusto: Enums generally should not have state. You're asking for trouble in various ways if you make them stateful.

Comment: But what you're talking about is an error in the serialization logic, not the support for serialization itself. Singletons by definition may only be instantiated once, which means a proper serialization strategy would only persist it once or overwrite on multiple persistence.

Comment: @ColinD 100% agree, but some singletons need to maintain state... I think what I'm trying to say that the ENUM solution might not be the **best** but a good solution in some cases.

Comment: @Augusto: Using the static instance Singleton pattern for stateful objects or objects that you might want to not use in testing is a bad idea in general, whether you use an enum for it or not. There are lots of simple, stateless uses for a singleton where an enum singleton is nice though.

Comment: @Augusto - singletons with anything beyond simple states are a no-no. In 17 years of work I've not seen a legitimate use of a singleton with a complex state *at the language level*. A rare singleton with a legitimate complex state is/should be an infrastructure/runtime artifact  (and not an application-level one) that should belong to an underlying runtime (the JVM, a managed container or the OS.) Think java.lang.System or java.lang.Runtime. A singleton with zero or very simple state can be trivially made serializable by simply having serializable attributes (whether it is done as an enum.)

Comment: @Augusto - con't. For anything more complex (**and legitimate as part of a well-designed model**), you need to rely on some infrastructure that gives you *singleton* management guarantees (like Spring's singleton deployment mode), **and** the singleton itself must manage its own serialization, most likely on its own custom serialization/activation/passivation lifecycle (as opposed to just simply implementing *java.io.Serializable*.) A lot of elbow grease. In reality, Singleton is abused a lot, and singletons with complex states are much more often than not, a code/modeling smell.

Comment: @Augusto - con't - that is, in the general case (which is the one that should count the most), in java, Enum based Singletons are the *best* way to go. So, it is not as you said, that they are just a good solution *in some cases*. It is the best for the majority of cases that legitimately require a true, well-designed singleton. Anything else is a rare edge case, legitimate but rare, or a bad design artifact.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

yes  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think if you deserialize a serialized singleton more then once you might end up with more than one instance. An enum instance will always stay a singleton.

So you get 'more serialization' then what you get from just implementing serialization.